# Why do we lost stdout from a terminal after running subprocess.check_output(xyz, shell=True)?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have this bash line:

```
$ printf '  Number of xml files: %s\n' `find . -name '*.xml' | wc -l`
  Number of xml files: 4
$
```

When I run it from python in this way **the python interpreter stop** and my terminal **does not have stdout anymore**::

```
$ ls
input aa bb
$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
>>>
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = "printf  'xml files: %s\n' `find . -name '*.xml' | wc -l`"
>>> subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', cmd], shell=True)
$ ls  # stdout is not seen any more I have to kill this terminal
$
```

Obviously the question here is not how to make this bash work from python::

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = "printf  'xml files: %s\n' `find . -name '*.xml' | wc -l`"
>>> out = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print(str(out.stdout, 'utf8'))
xml files: 4

>>>
```

The two following issues [No output from subprocess.check_output()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611658/no-output-from-subprocess-check-output) and [Why is terminal blank after running python executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540278/why-is-terminal-blank-after-running-python-executable) does not answer the question

Comment: tried raw output? `cmd = r"printf  'xml files: ...\n"`. Because this `\n` char probably blocks the shell

Comment: Why `['/bin/bash', cmd]` and not `['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd]`? `bash` expects its argument to be a file. The `-c` option causes it to read the script from the argument.

Comment: why bash at all? this can be done with pure python with `os.walk` with a filter, then open the file and use `len` on the list of lines...

Comment: also, in the command that works, you're not using `bash` prefix at all. Those 2 aren't equivalent.

Comment: Thank you Jean-François, but the question is not - are the two cmd equivalent neither how to make work the subprocess.check_output line, but how can be explained the fact that 1. python exit to terminal 2. terminal does not has any stdout pluged any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is that `check_output` is buffering all the output to return. When you run `ls`, its standard output is going to `check_output`'s buffer, not the terminal. When you exit the shell you are currently in, you'll get all the output at once as a single Python string.

This leads to the question, why are you getting a sub shell in the first place, instead of executing the contents of `cmd`? First, you are using `bash` wrong; its argument is a *file* to run, not an arbitrary command line. A more correct version of what you are doing would be

```
cmd = "printf  'xml files: %s\n' `find . -name '*.xml' | wc -l`"
subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd])
```

or, if you want `subprocess` to run a shell for you, instead of explicitly executing it,

```
subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

Combining the list argument with `shell=True` is almost never what you want.

Second, given your original code, `check_output` first tries to combine your list into a single string, which is then joined to `sh -c`. That is, you try to execute something like

```
sh -c /bin/bash "printf  'xml files: %s\n' `find . -name '*.xml' | wc -l`"
```

`sh` runs `/bin/bash`, and your command string is just used as an additional argument to `sh` which, for the purposes of this question, we can assume is ignored. So you are in an interactive shell whose standard output is buffered instead of displayed, as described in the first part of this answer.